# Extract full data from *.pickle file

Tags: python

Pickle file is stored in binary form and I want to know is there any way to convert this  file into unicode and store it in *.txt file.

I am using a toolkit where the output is stored in a *.pickle file. 
Now I want to read the output of that *.pickle  file  and I am using the following commands

```
with open('filename','rb') as f:
    abc = pickle.load(f)
```

Now when I am writing " abc " in python shell this is not displaying the full file. The *.pickle file is a huge file and while displaying it on terminal it is not showing the full file. Then I  tried write this file into  some other *.txt file but again it is giving some errors. Method to convert it to *.txt file is

```
f = open("pul.txt", "w")
f.write(abc)      
f.close()
```

But it is giving the error and not writing the data from *.pickle file into "pul.txt".
I want to know how can I check the full data in *.pickle file, e.g., If I have to grep certain things from this *.pickle file how will I do ? Is there any way ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show the full error. Also, a small example of the structure of the data (decoded) would be good. Finally, I think you may not realise that a pickle file contains an object graph. In general, you need to convert the object graph to a string yourself before you write it. My favorite choice for that would be jsonpickle (I am an author).

Comment: note you are reading bytes `rb`, but writing as if it was a string `w` - is pickle supposed to do the conversion by itself?

Comment: What should the string representation look like?  Is the pickled object a list, dictionary, tuple etc that has a clear string representation?